# Django display json data table

Tags: python, json, django, solr

I'm currently unable to display json data from solr that crawls twitter API tweets.

I would like to display them in a table form so that it would be easier to view and add additional UI stuff later.

Here's my code:

my views.py

```
def my_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        gotName = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
        gotEmotion = form.cleaned_data['emotion']
        gotWords = form.cleaned_data['words']


        url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/query?q=id:' + gotName
        r = requests.post(url, data={'id': gotName})

        return render(request, 'index.html', {"table_data" : ??? })
        #return render(request, 'index.html', {"mydata": mydata})


else:
    not_working = "not working"

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'text2': not_working })
```

my index.html table part:

```
<table>

# insert table formatting here

</table>
```

full index.html body:

```
<body>

{%  load static %}
<img src="{% static "/templates/happybird.jpg" %}"/>

<h1 style="text-align:center;">Emotional Tweets</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">

            <form action="/search/my_view/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
                <div>

                    <input id="your_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name"  placeholder="Search for Tweets" value="{{ current_name }}" />
                    <br>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="0" selected>All Tweets</option>
                        <option value="1">Excited</option>
                        <option value="2">Happy</option>
                        <option value="3">Neutral</option>
                        <option value="4">Sad</option>
                        <option value="5">Angry</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                    <input id="words" class="form-control" type="text" name="words" value="{{ current_words }}" />
                </div>


                <input type="submit" value="OK">
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<p>{{ text2 }}</p>
<p>{{ text3 }}</p>
<table>

# insert table formatting here ???

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</body>
```

currently the response r.text displays the raw json in text form for the query a* from my solr crawled data.

[image]

so I need help with processing the json data into a table format to display in the html.